# trying to minus two times to result the time spent

Tags: c#

i am trying to minus the time as bellow C# code

```
    cmd.CommandText = "update TECHNOVA_SMS_TICKET set ISSUE_STATUS='" + statuchange + "' , SMS_CLOSED_TIME= '" + closedTime.Text + "' , SMS_TIME_SPENT= '+ NVL(24 * (to_date(" + closedTime.Text + ",'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM') - to_date(" + currecT + ",'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM')),0)' where SMS_TICKET_ID='" + issueId + "'";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  

    issueclosedsucess.Text = " Issue is Closed. Acknowlege!";
    issueclosedsucess.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;

    dashboardissue();
```

the error is Additional information: External component has thrown an exception.

Comment: I think it's better if you show us the final string stored in cmd.CommandText (hover over CommandText and copy the string).

Comment: Use parameters. Do not concatenate strings to create sql statement as it's an open door for sql injection attacks.

Comment: You know the error isn't in the C# code?

Comment: this the final string--update TECHNOVA_SMS_TICKET set ISSUE_STATUS='Closed' , SMS_CLOSED_TIME= '10/1/2017 3:48:02 PM', SMS_TIME_SPENT= '+ NVL(24 * (to_date(10/1/2017 3:48:02 PM,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM') - to_date(9/14/2017 7:21:57 PM,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM')),0)' where SMS_TICKET_ID='183'";

Comment: @ Zohar Peled what dose it mean? what is concatenate strings ? Give an example